# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cryptography_OAEPDecoding'

Tags: c#, exception, encryption, rsa

i have a program that has to decrypt 3 phrases using a RSA privateKey but keeps showing that exception above, System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Cryptography_OAEPDecoding', what do i need to change for it to work?, i've tried seeing other pages but its too confusing, and i end up adding too many commented code and starting again.

[Exception that pops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML0nR.png)

Comment: Direct up-vote for providing a reproducible example!

Comment: Thankfully there's history, since the example has been deleted 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs because you explicitly tell the RSA crypto service provider to use [OAEP padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) but your ciphers are encrypted using PKCS1 padding.

```
// Your current statement:
var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(resultBytes, true);
```

The second parameter (fOAEP is documented like:

```
//   fOAEP:
//     true to perform direct System.Security.Cryptography.RSA decryption using
//     OAEP padding (only available on a computer running Microsoft Windows XP or
//     later); otherwise, false to use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.
```

So by just changing to false;

```
var decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(resultBytes, false);
```

We get the following output:

```
INICIO DE LA SEGUNDA PARTE
M A N D A   C O R R E O   A   J A V I E R   B E L
C O N   T U   N O M B R E   C O M P L E T O
Y   L A   F E C H A / H O R A
```

Important side note:

Probably while copy/pasting, your base64 ciphers are incorrect. I corrected them like this:

```
var FRASE1 = "IlmhPFKroDuK4AUtBGfaf5J6791DzMenkUBEXfRwZ7rmBHswHTf02LAba/Hs+rsh3wL6dpMQlEhlaIAVHaZZsw==";
var FRASE2 = "AMbsYR1pq9WYUj3mdqKvJj7tMznqBAcZLxM2C6WzNEUOqKD/qdEE76bNJPmYFKwVei2rhuHFsxh7nUzXmVKRdw==";
var FRASE3 = "J1jnq551phV+W4MVzE5caXIHqM3E0gz/t9PVtorqvDVqfne8CCF9UQiEk33Rssi1IEz6JH8Fd8ZAvnX3UWe5Vw==";
```

Comment: done, marked as the answer dont have enough repotation to give you the upvote, i would if i could, thanks a lot.